# Dependency injection in Constructor

Tags: java, spring, jsf, dependency-injection

Suppose that I have Spring service classes or JSF beans. I wire these classes in another class. There are no problems till now. I can use these injected fields in any method.

But, using them in the constructor gives me a NullPointerException.

Probably the constructor runs before dependency injection happens, and it doesn't see my injected fields. Is there any solution to use dependency injection in a constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, it's not possible to inject anything in an object if this object doesn't exist. And to exist, an object must be constructed.

Spring supports constructor injection:

```
@Autowired
public SomeService(SomeDependency dep) {
    ...
```

Spring also supports [@PostConstruct](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations.), which allows initializing a bean after all the dependencies have been injected.

Don't know about JSF.

Comment: Well [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) is an EJB annotation, so it's obviously supported in JavaEE. And [`@Ìnject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) is applicable to constructors, too.

Comment: @Sean: it's not an EJB annotation. It's part of Java SE API. But it's indeed seen the most in combination with EJBs.

Comment: @BalusC formally that may be true, but the documentation explicitly mentions the EJB spec.

Answer (score 5):

No you cannot refer to injected fields in the constructor. The framework must construct your object somehow (call a constructor) and then inject dependencies so they are empty during constructor execution. What you usually do instead is applying `@PostConstruct` annotation to one of your methods and perform initialization there:

```
class MyBean {
  @Inject 
  private MyDependency myDep;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    assert myDep != null;
  }
}
```

In case of spring xml configuration you can use `init-method="init"` instead of `@PostConstruct` in your `<bean>` definition. Alternatively you can use constructor injection, in xml:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="my.package.MyBean">
  <constructor-arg ref="myDependency/>
</bean>
```

or annotation equivalent.

Comment: Yeah using @postConstruct can be solution instead use constructor

Comment: As an additional fact, `@PostConstruct` can be used even on a `private` init method. Setting the init method to private visibility may be useful to have a clean, uncluttered public API. (see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html )